# Linkedin member profile in angular 2

Tags: linkedin-api

When I put this in the template, it does not run. It is in the page source:

```
<script type="IN/MemberProfile" data-id="https://www.linkedin.com/in/..." data-format="inline" data-related="false"></script>
```

Is it possible to use this plugin directly in Angular 2?